# Stop <p> from moving when scrolling webpage in HTML

Tags: html, css

In this page, a paragraph element will scroll up if I scroll up but the background stays fixed. I want the background and paragraph elements to stay fixed while the next div appears.

It's hard to say in words, but I want the first div, the landing page, to act as if it were a blind on a window. Scrolling up will replace the bottom of the first div with the corresponding bottom part of the second div, just like pulling up the blinds on your window.

Here's a **jsfiddle** http://jsfiddle.net/2cT4z/1/.

I want to make the text block fixed and scroll the page up so that the bottom of the second page appears going down to up.

**CSS Code:**

```
#slide-1 .bcg {
    background-image:url('http://1.bp.blogspot.com/_29xyRBNmNa8/TI5L2xIdDcI/AAAAAAAAALk/gSiP4fVuRkU/s1600/woods.jpg');  
    background-position: center center;
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    background-attachment: fixed;
    background-size: cover;
    height: 700px;
    width: 100%;
}
```

Comment: Sounds like you want to do some kind of parallax scrolling.  Have a look at this lib to see if it helps: http://prinzhorn.github.io/skrollr/

Comment: @blurfus I'm not sure which parallax effect applies to the one I'm looking for. I'm guessing it's something that replaces the pixels at the bottom locations with the exact pixels of the next screen, but I don't know how to implement that in CSS

Comment: Did you mean something like this? http://polarblau.github.io/stickySectionHeaders/

Comment: ^No, I meant something like the first page where the paragraph and the background don't move, but the page after it, when scrolling up, replaces the previous screen. Again, it's imperative that neither the background or HTML elements move when scrolling up or down

Comment: "Stop <p> from moving when scrolling webpage" - Hmmm, absolute positioning?